# Помогите разобрать что написано на крестике?

Tags: старославянский, славянские-языки

Никак не могу разобрать мелкую надпись, представляю какие надписи бывают на крестиках обычно, но эта мне незнакома. Помогите, пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разобрала, вдруг кому поможет: «Да воскреснет Бог, и расточатся врази его, и да бежат»